# How can I get the kinect pose with rgbdslam v2

Tags: slam, navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am working with rgbdslam v2 to make the turtlebot navigate in door, so I want to get the pose of kinect. I have get the trajectory of camera, but I didn't find out how to get the rotation of the kinect.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/197565/how-can-i-get-the-kinect-pose-with-rgbdslam-v2./) by [NKUBRUCE](https://answers.ros.org/users/20833/nkubruce/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2014-11-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you want it online, you can subscribe to /tf and use the transformation between /map (or whatever you use for the parameter "fixed_frame_name") to the frame of the kinect (/openni_camera or /camera_link).
The trajectory file has the following format:

```
timestamp x-position y-position z-position quaternion-x quaternion-y quaternion-z quaternion-w
```

The timestamp is the typical unix stamp in seconds, positions are in meter, rotation is a normalized quaternion.

For example:

```
1305033527.670034 0.002149 -0.002778 0.000684 -0.001445 -0.000679 -0.000384 0.999999
```

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2015-01-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [NKUBRUCE](https://answers.ros.org/users/20833/nkubruce/) on 2015-01-18**:
Thank you very much!